# Proof of compatible $[Y_1,Y_2](g) =Y_1[Y_2(g)]-Y_2(Y_1(g)) =X_1[X_2(g\circ \Phi)]-X_2(X_1(g\circ \Phi))$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, lie-algebras, tangent-spaces

Quote:

> "Let $X_1,Y_1$ and $X_2,Y_x$ be two pairs of vectors fields compatible by $\Phi$. 
>   Then $[X_1,X_2]$ and $[Y_1,Y_2]$ are compatible by $\Psi$. Consider $P\in M$ and $Q=\Phi(P)$, and let $g$ be a $C^2$ function in a neighborhood of $Q$. Then $
> [Y_1,Y_2](g)
> =Y_1[Y_2(g)]-Y_2(Y_1(g))
> =X_1[X_2(g\circ \Phi)]-X_2(X_1(g\circ \Phi))
> =[X_1,X_2](g\circ \Phi)
> $."

During the step $Y_1[Y_2(g)]-Y_2(Y_1(g))
=X_1[X_2(g\circ \Phi)]-X_2(X_1(g\circ \Phi))$, 
looking at the term $Y_1[Y_2(g)]
=X_1[X_2(g\circ \Phi)]$. 
By the definition of compatible, 
$[(Y_{2})_Q](g)
=[(Y_2)_{\Phi(P)}](g)
=[(\Phi_*)_PX(P)](g)
=X_P(g\circ\Phi)$
That I could understand. However, how did $Y_1\rightarrow X_1$ in the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields compatible by $\Phi$, i.e. $Y\circ \Phi = T\Phi\circ X$, or equivalently $Y_{\Phi(P)} = T_P\Phi(X_P)$ for all $P$. Then $Y_{\Phi(P)}g = T_P\Phi(X_P)(g) = X_P(g\circ \Phi)$, or in other words, 
$$Y(g)\circ\Phi = X(g\circ\Phi).$$ 
Applying this twice
$$
Y_1(Y_2(g))\circ \Phi = X_1(Y_2(g)\circ\Phi) = X_1(X_2(g\circ\Phi)),
$$
and so
$$
[Y_1,Y_2](g)\circ\Phi = [X_1,X_2](g\circ\Phi).
$$
If you're being sloppy, you can leave out the $\Phi$ on the left hand side, as done in your quote.